# Proving commutativity of max in coq

Tags: coq

I have a function `max`:

```
Fixpoint max (n : nat) (m : nat) : nat :=
  match n, m with
    | O, O => O
    | O, S x => S x
    | S x, O => S x
    | S x, S y => S (max x y)
  end.
```

and a proof of the commutativity of `max` as follows:

```
Theorem max_comm :
  forall n m : nat, max n m = max m n.
Proof.
  intros n m.
  induction n as [|n'];
    induction m as [|m'];
      simpl; trivial.
(* Qed. *)
```

This leaves off at `S (max n' m') = S (max m' n')`, which seems correct, and given the base case has already been proven, seems like one should be able to tell coq "just use the recursion!". However, I cannot figure out how to do it. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you introduce variable `m` before doing induction on variable `n`, and that makes the induction hypothesis less general. Try this instead.

```
intro n; induction n as [| n' IHn'];
  intro m; destruct m as [| m'];
    simpl; try (rewrite IHn'); trivial.
```

Comment: Walking through the cases, it now makes a lot more sense as to why one would `destruct m` instead of `induction m`. Thanks!